# How do you accompany other veggies with caramelized onions?

Tags: sauce, onions, caramelization

I assume that when you caramelize onions and would want your dish to also have caramelized carrots it would have to be more complex than just throw the carrots along the onions to the pot.

Any idea on how to pair carrots (or any other veggies) to a flavor base made of caramelized onions?

Answer (score 2):

Carrots and onions have different cooking times, so no, you can't throw them together.

What I would do is cut the carrots as small as the onions (just for aesthetic purposes), start stewing the carrots in a closed pot *first* and season them as you like, and when they're nearly done, add the onions and caramelise them normally while they're stewing together with the carrots and you'll end up with caramelised carrot-onion stew.

Obviously, you can always cook them separately and then mix them just before serving, but that would take an additional pot and I don't like doing dishes...  **;-)**

Comment: To complement the answer, cooking time is key here, also if you're looking for texture you might want to consider cooking one ingredient at a time (without changing pot, rather by removing cooked ingredient and cook the other ingredient in the same pot, since we all hate doing dishes :P)